# Трансфер файла между микросервисами open feign

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

возможно кто-то сталкивался с задачей по передаче файлов между микросервисами.
Суть задачи: есть микросервис **A**, в котором нужно получить файл из микросервиса **B** и оправить его в микросервис **C**.
Я перепробывал наверное все варианты, но постоянно упираюсь в ошибки.
В начале я использовал **Open feign** для этого. API микросервиса **B** отдает файл в структуре FileSystemResource, принять его в такой структуре я не могу, поскольку нету http конвертеров. Поэтому приходится принимать его как **spring Resource**, либо как **feign Request**.
Окей, я принял входящие байты от микросервиса **B**, но дальше их передать нет возможности.
Микросервис **C**, который ожидает **@RequestParam(MultipartFile)** ничего не хочет принимать.
Если скрафтить свой MultipartFile через переопределение методов интерфейса, возникает ошибка, что отсутсвует boundary в запросе.
Если поменять аннотацию в фейн клиенте на @RequestPart, то система ругается, что нету подходях конвертеров для такого.
Поэтому я использовал RestTemplate для передачи, но не для получения.

```
MultiValueMap<String,Object> j =  new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

                  j.add("file", file.body()/*file bytes[]*/);


                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

                    headers.set("Authorization",request.getHeader("Authorization"));

                    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> ob = new HttpEntity<>(j,headers);
                    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

                   try {
                       ResponseEntity<CertificateDtoV3> qq = rest.postForEntity(url, ob, CertificateDtoV3.class, id);
                   }catch (Exception e){
                       e.printStackTrace();

                   }
```

Теперь вся проблема в том, что данный метод всегда падает c `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`
Я думаю, что это возникает из-за передаваемых байтов в теле запроса.
Собственно сам вопрос, могу ли я получить файл из микросервиса **B** в виде, подходящим для передачи в микросервис **C**, либо как-то донастроить RestTemplate

Comment: мне кажется, неплозо было бы добавить сюда описание вашей задачи/проблемы, что вы решаете. Например, если бы я писал систему, которая рабьотала бы с файлами, я бы для доступа к файлам сделал отдельный микросервис. Хотя и тут многое зависит от требований, ведь если все вашид файлы размером с перу килобайт, то любое решение сойдет. Но если оперировать файлами с гигабайт, тут уже другое дело.

Comment: Задача как раз таки и заключается в просто передаче файлов между тремя микросервисами и парсингом сертификата в промежутке между передачами. Вес - около 3 килобайт(сертификаты безопасности). Да, отдельный микросервис имеется, как раз тот, из которого я пытаюсь получить файлы, но у меня нет доступа к ним, приходится работать только в своем микросервисе с тем, что предоставлят другие